# System Menu and Delegates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, delegates, event-handling

As you have seen the system menus , they have a syntax like this :

```
MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
MenuItem fileMenuItem = new MenuItem("File");

mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(fileMenuItem);
this.Menu = mainMenu;
```

To Write Events For Click events , Can I Do something like this ? how ?

```
fileMenuItem.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("New",
MyMenuItemEventArgs(this, new MyMenuItemEventArgs("New")))
```

So In MyMenuItemEventArgs , I Can pass my opearion to one function which operates.in this case I have passed 'New'.

I don't want to write 10 or more handlers , i want just write one handler with many Event args.

Comment: Wire all of the menu items to use the same handler method, then use the `sender` parameter to differentiate which menu item raised the event. Cast it from `System.Object` to `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate a new menuItem, then use the Click attribute to add the handler.

```
MenuItem menuItem1=new MenuItem("Item text");

menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(handler_method);
```

After that you can add it to your menu:

```
fileMenuItem.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
```

Comment: I don't want to make many handler methods . I want just use one handler method with many event args!

Comment: If you are trying to have one handler for many buttons being pressed, then you should use the "sender" object that is being passed as a parameter to indicate which button has been pressed. that way you can determine in your global handler what actions to take based on the button being pressed. IF this is what you want to achieve. You can assign each button the information you want (like in your example you assigned "New" to that button).

Answer (score 1):

The value of `EventArgs` parameter is provided by the object firing the event, which is `MenuItem` in this case. So the only way to handle the `OnClick` event of multiple `MenuItem` objects in one handler is by using the `sender` parameter. You could check which menu item was clicked using some code like this:

```
var mainMenu = new MainMenu();
var fileMenuItem = new MenuItem("file");
var openMenuItem = new MenuItem("open", OnClick);
var exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("exit", OnClick);

openMenuItem.Name = "open";
exitMenuItem.Name = "exit";

fileMenuItem.MenuItems.Add(openMenuItem);
fileMenuItem.MenuItems.Add(exitMenuItem);

mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(fileMenuItem);
this.Menu = mainMenu;
```

And in the event handler:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var senderName = ((MenuItem) sender).Name;
    if (senderName == "open")
    {
        //open was clicked
    }
    else if (senderName == "exit")
    {
        //exit was clicked
    }
}
```